# Extending a TypeScript interface with values from another object

Tags: typescript

I have the following interface:

```js
export interface IFormField {
    /** Field name */
    name: string;

    /** Label to appear on form */
    label?: string;   // this is optional, since hidden fields do not have label

    /** Field type */
    type: 'accordion' | 'address' | 'camera' | 'category_box' | 'category_list';
}
```

and I'd like to extend the valid values of `type` picking them by an object like this one:

```js
const arr = {
   'new_type1': 1,
   'new_type2': 2,
   'new_type3': 3,
};
```

How do I add `new_type1`, `new_type2` and `new_type3` to the list of valid names in the `type` field?

As a result, I'd like to have:

```js
type: 'accordion' | 'address' | 'camera' | 'category_box' | 'category_list' | `new_type1` | `new_type2` | `new_type3`;
```

For another complete (not working) example:

```js
const arr: any = {
   'new_type1': 1,
   'new_type2': 2,
   'new_type3': 3,
};

export interface IFormField {
    /** Field name */
    name: string;

    /** Label to appear on form */
    label?: string;   // this is optional, since hidden fields do not have label

    /** Field type */
    type: keyof typeof arr;
}

const f: IFormField = {
    name: 'ciao',
    type: "new_type1"
};

// adding a new key to `arr` at runtime
arr.type4 = 4;

const g: IFormField = {
    name: 'cioa',
    type: 'type4'  // <- valid for IFormField.type ?
}
```

Is it possible?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is easy to construct the desired type:

- capture the new keys in type `NewFieldTypes`
- make an union of old types and new types
- lastly, substitute the type field in `IFormField`

```ts
export interface IFormField {
    /** Field name */
    name: string;

    /** Label to appear on form */
    label?: string;   // this is optional, since hidden fields do not have label

    /** Field type */
    type: 'accordion' | 'address' | 'camera' | 'category_box' | 'category_list';
}

const arr = {
   'new_type1': 1,
   'new_type2': 2,
   'new_type3': 3,
};

type NewFieldTypes = keyof typeof arr;
type ExpandedFieldTypes = IFormField['type'] | NewFieldTypes

type ExpandedIFormField = Omit<IFormField, "type"> & {
  type: ExpandedFieldTypes
};
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=24&ssc=1&pln=12&pc=1#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBASwHY2FAZgQwMbDgSQDFoBbQhYAGwBM4BvAKDmbgHoAqducq2pTEnnasmLfoIBccAM4woyAOYBuBqOYcuAGUwAjKnBgQ4mMGGCYocCEjjpScYWriVdVAPxTZ8pMpatWBgAWCNKIoRBgMAjWmJQANDLIuHDB1NTANugUNKHURkgQ8IGYAG54LnqUqixsnNzZtDAAnmYOIjXNZlIA5DjY0NTRSN1wAD5wvWlQwNLSI%20Pd2AJomPMTS6gK0E0A%20joQIGuLmJvbO5QhMN0qAL6q-UiyxlCWALz0at1IwADuO53AACM3SkgLin2%20fwBACYQXBoeCWF9fv8WsAAMxw9Hgm4qBgAuAAOV%20PBoABU0aF3gBrYBNCDoAxohnPKAqAkAUXAmCQ6WopOoFLMVIIxCgZAaAG1ugDugBdMZEkkNIUzVSc7m84DUIikAVwd4AeRICBgAB5deKBQkAEQAm0APjgADIPswAVIuWAeXyBarpAxcfdrE8srxPZq%20ZaJbwDW64OJgD10MDEUyuhNIaizMDA0A)

Comment: Thanks, I have updated the question because my starting `arr` is not a type, but a key / values object and I need to change its values at runtime, yet having the type check while coding.

Comment: The compiler has no way of knowing what you add to the array at runtime (could be user-provided input) so it cannot enforce it. The best you can do is to allow any string.

Answer (score 0):

```
type MyCombinedUnion = keyof typeof arr | IFormField["type"]
```

https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.3.5&ssl=19&ssc=6&pln=19&pc=21#code/FAUwHgDg9gTgLgAgJYDs4hgMwIYGMQICSAYrALbFIgA2AJggN7AIsID0AVBwpTfStjIEObZqwFCAXAgDOcGKgDmAbmBiWnbgBlsAIxoI4UBNggQQ2GAigoEmcghHqE1PTQD80uQpQrWbNkMACyQZZDCoCDgkG2xqABpZVHwEENpaEFtMKjow2mMUKEQg7AA3Ald9ajVWdi4eHPo4AE9zR1FalvNpAHI8XFhaGJQehAAfBD70mBAZGVGJntxBDGwFyeX0RVhmgH1dKDB1pewtnd3qULge1QBfNQGUORMYKwBeRnUelBAAd12uiAAIw9aRA+JfH7-QEAJlBCBhENY3z+ANaIAAzPCMRDbqpgICEABZZoAYSgZF0qBAtAAqihhggPgBrEDNKCYQzojkvKwTEjkXh0ADaACJAaKALpAA